# DDD and Ent Lib

Tags: domain-driven-design, enterprise-library, ddd-repositories

Are there any sample applications available that show implementing DDD with Enterprise Library 5.0.

Comment: I am afraid DDD has nothing to do with EntLib... What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: DDD is a design philosophy. It has nothing to do with any particular library or framework. The closest you can come is to say that a framework was designed with DDD in mind (like Sharp Architecture).

Comment: I mean Enterprise Library for Data Access. But what I really want is a full sample of DDD Pattern (Entities, VOs, Aggregates, etc)

Comment: Entlib's data block is really just a shallow wrapper around ADO.NET to make it less annoying to use. It doesn't affect how you'd actually structure your data access. If you're seriously into DDD I'd suggest instead looking at one of the many great ORM solutions (NHibernate and Entity Framework being the big two right now), as they already supply a lot of what you'd need to build by hand if you're using Entlib.

Answer (score 0):

if you have interesting then have a look this project

http://code.google.com/p/ironframework/